# Getting user id from email using System.DirectoryServices.Protocols Ldap

Tags: c#, .net-core, active-directory, ldap-query

I am trying to get user id from email id using `System.DirectoryServices.Protocols`.

With help of `System.DirectoryServices` we can get it but solution works only for windows through LDAP connection like below

```
dirSearcher.Filter = "(&(objectClass=user)(objectcategory=person)(mail=" + emailId + "*))";

SearchResult agentADDetails = dirSearcher.FindOne();

String userid = agentADDetails.Properties["samaccountname"][0].ToString();
```

For Linux systems we need to use `System.DirectoryServices.Protocols` but not sure how we can get same information ?

Any help or working example will be appreciate.

Regards,
Gopal